# Country name converter to ISO

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to make a World chart that also shows how many transactions are coming from certain country's. But i need to translate the name of the country's to ISO because that is the only way this chart will work. Also the transactions is String (It is actually type of transactions) so i am trying to kind of convert the strings to numbers as well. I don't know if i am doing that right as well.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
var xmlURL = "some url";
var xml;
    var xmlData;
    var countryCodeColumn = "Counterparty country";
    var categoryColumn = "Type of transaction";


    var map;
    var jsonText = "{";
    var mapData;
    var regionStyling = {initial: {fill: '#93959b'}};

$j.ajax({
    url:xmlURL,
    dataType:"xml",
    beforeSend: function(){
        $j('#loader').show();
    },
    success: function(data){
        xml = data;
        drawMap();
        $j('#loader').hide();

    }
});


function drawMap(){
console.log("xml as text", (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xml));
    var columns = {};
    var columnNames = [];
    var xmlColumns = $j('head', xml);
    xmlColumns.find('headColumn').each(function(){
        var columnName = $j(this).find('columnValue').text();
        var columnID = $j(this).attr('columnid');       
        columns[columnName] = columnID;
        console.log("column",columnName,columnID);
    });

    var xmlData = $j('data', xml);
    var countryCode;
    var category;
    var categoryColor;

    var url;

xmlData.find('item').each(function(){
    itemId = $j(this).find('itemID').text();
            url = "./injectColumnViewItemPage.action?metaData.channelID=9&metaData.siteID=723&metaData.sheetId=4640&metaData.itemId=" + itemId + "&metaData.sheetViewID=0&metaData.viewMode=0&view=readonly&sheetItemLinkView=true";
            console.log("url", url);
            console.log("itemid", itemId);
            $j(this).find('column').each(function(){
            var colID = $j(this).attr("columnid");
console.log(colID);
            var value = $j(this).find('displayData').text();
                            console.log("field:", colID,value);

        if(colID == columns[countryCodeColumn]){
            countryCode = value;

                    }else if(colID == columns[categoryColumn]){
                            if(value != 0){
                                category++;
                            }
            category = value;
                            categoryColor = $j(this).find('rawData').find('choice').attr('style');
            }
                            });
                            jsonText += '"' + countryCode + '":{' + '"Transactions":"' + category + '","Color":"' + categoryColor + '","ItemID":' + itemId + '},';
                            });
                            jsonText = jsonText.substring(0,jsonText.length-1) + "}";
                            console.log("jsontext", jsonText);
                            mapData = JSON.parse(jsonText);
                            console.log("json", JSON.stringify(mapData));

                            map = new jvm.Map({container: $j('#isheet-map'),
                            map: 'world_mill_en',
                            series:{
                                regions: [{
                                        normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
                                }]
                            },
                            zoomOnScroll: true, 
                            regionStyle: regionStyling, 
                            backgroundColor: "#ffffff", 
                            onRegionTipShow: function(e,el,code)
                            {
                            if(mapData[code])
                            {
                                el.html('<div style = "line-height:50%;"><span class="map-tip-title">' + el.html() + '</span><p></p><span class="map-tip-label">Transactions:</span>' + mapData[code]["Transactions"] + '<p></p></div>');   
                            }else{
                            return false;
                                    }
                                    },
                            onRegionClick: function(e, code){
                            if(mapData[code]){


                                var href ="./injectColumnViewItemPage.action?metaData.channelID=9&metaData.siteID=" + 723 + "&metaData.sheetId=" + 4640 + "&metaData.itemId=" + mapData[code]["itemId"] + "&metaData.sheetViewID=0&metaData.viewMode=0&view=readonly&sheetItemLinkView=true";
                           $j("#iframe-Map").attr('src', href);
                           $j("#map-dialog").dialog({modal: true, title: map.getRegionName(code), width:600, height:500});
                                        }
                                        else{

                                        return false;
                                            }
                                    }
                                    });

                                    map.series.regions[0].setValues(getColors());

                                    function getColors(){
                                    var colors = {};
                                        $j.each(mapData,function(code,val){
                                        colors[code] = mapData[code]["Color"];
                                                });
                                                console.log("colors", colors);
                                                return colors;
                                            }
                                            }

</script>
```

There is nothing wrong with my ajax code since if i link it to another url it works fine

Comment: @evolutionxbox why won't `xml = data;` do as expected?

Comment: Nevermind. I misunderstood something.